# Getting error - A column id is required if using a non-string accessor for column above - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am following this example of React Table - https://codesandbox.io/s/n2gqAxl7

I have a React Table which will have 13 columns, for few columns we have sub columns while for few columns we have individual columns.

[image: Image of my desired columns]

Suppose in this table columns 1 to 10 are independent. While in column 11 to 13 we have the concept of parent column and sub column.

In first 10 columns the columns will have no accessor while column 6 to 10 will have the accessor of the above column (1 to 5) in one line and their own (6 to 10) accessor in a new line.

I have mainly modified the constant called columns

```
    const columns = [{
  id: 'col16',
  Header: () => {
    (
      <div>
        <div className="col1">
          Col 1
            </div>
        <div className="col6">
          Col 6
            </div>
      </div>
    );
  },
  accessor: (d) => { return (d.firstname + d.lastName); },
  width: 200
},
{
  id: 'col27',
  Header: () => {
    (
      <div>
        <div className="col2">
          Col 2
            </div>
        <div className="col7">
          Col 7
            </div>
      </div>
    );
  },
  accessor: (d) => { return (d.firstname + d.lastName); },
  width: 200
},
{
  id: 'col38',
  Header: () => {
    (
      <div>
        <div className="col3">
          Col 3
            </div>
        <div className="col8">
          Col 8
            </div>
      </div>
    );
  },
  accessor: (d) => { return (d.firstname + d.lastName); },
  width: 200
},
{
  id: 'col49',
  Header: () => {
    (
      <div>
        <div className="col4">
          Col 4
            </div>
        <div className="col9">
          Col 9
            </div>
      </div>
    );
  },
  accessor: (d) => { return (d.firstname + d.lastName); },
  width: 200
},
{
  id: 'col510',
  Header: () => {
    (
      <div>
        <div className="col5">
          Col 5
            </div>
        <div className="col10">
          Col 10
            </div>
      </div>
    );
  },
  accessor: (d) => { return (d.firstname + d.lastName); },
  width: 200
},
{
  id: 'col11',
  Header: 'Col 11',
  columns: [
    {
      Header: 'Sub Col 11a',
      accessor: (d) => { return (d.firstname); },
      width: 80,
    },
    {
      Header: 'Sub Col 11b',
      accessor: (d) => { return (d.firstname); },
      width: 80
    },
    {
      Header: 'Sub Col 11c',
      accessor: (d) => { return (d.firstname); },
      width: 80
    },
    {
      Header: 'Sub Col 11d',
      accessor: (d) => { return (d.firstname); },
      width: 80
    }
  ]
},
{
  id: 'col12',
  Header: 'Col 12',
  columns: [
    {
      Header: 'Sub Col 12',
      accessor: (d) => { return (d.firstname); },
      width: 80
    }
  ]
},
{
  id: 'col13',
  Header: 'Col 13',
  columns: [
    {
      Header: 'Sub Col 13a',
      accessor: (d) => { return (d.firstname); },
      width: 80
    },
    {
      Header: 'Sub Col 13b',
      accessor: (d) => { return (d.firstname); },
      width: 80
    },
    {
      Header: 'Sub Col 13c',
      accessor: (d) => { return (d.firstname); },
      width: 80
    },
    {
      Header: 'Sub Col 13d',
      accessor: (d) => { return (d.firstname); },
      width: 80
    }
  ]
}];
```

I have also created a CodeSandbox. Here is my CodeSandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/lyn7r05p9

I am getting an error - A column id is required if using a non-string accessor for column above.

[image: My CodeSandbox]

I want help from other Stackoverflow members. Where I have done the mistake?

Comment: @Janaka Chathuranga Can you find where I made mistake?

Comment: @kiranvj Can you find where I made mistake?

Comment: @Jayce444 Can you find where I made mistake?

Answer (score 18):

You need to have id field in all columns with accessors. In your code you need to set id field for every inner column like that.

```
{
  id: 'col13',
  Header: 'Col 13',
  columns: [
    {
      Header: 'Sub Col 13a',
      id: 'sub_col_13a', // <-here
      accessor: (d) => { return (d.firstname); },
      width: 80
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For future readers if you already have `accessor` and it's not a function, just make sure it's a string. In my case it was a number and I had to convert it to string to solve the issue